# log : fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

Tags: git, neovim

I'm trying to install `lazy.nvim`. When downloaing neocinf.nvim, it failed.

I tried to set `user.name` and `user.email` to git config, but it stills fail. What should i do?

By the way, I also tried:`git config --global --add url."git@github.com:"`, instead of `"https://github.com/"`, still failed.

```
require("lazy").setup({
    "folke/which-key.nvim",
    {"folke/neocinf.nvim", cmd="Neoconf"},
    "folke/neodev.nvim",
})

require("lazy").setup(plugins, opts)
```

I'm new to lua script, is this correct?

Comment: it might be solved by place require("lazy").setup(plugins, opts) above require("lazy").setup({
    "folke/which-key.nvim",
    {"folke/neocinf.nvim", cmd="Neoconf"},
    "folke/neodev.nvim",
}), but i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove `'.nvim'` in the name, `use "folke/which-key"` instead
if the plugin ends with `.lua`,  you should add it to the name.
but if the plugin ends with `.nvim`, you should remove it